# How to dynamically load every needed function

Tags: c, windows, dll, loadlibrary, getprocaddress

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically load every Windows API function I need to use. For example, to use a the `printf` function, I do something like:

```
#include <windows.h>

typedef int (*printfPtr)(const char *str, ...);
int main(){
    HMODULE handle = LoadLibraryA("crtdll.dll");
    if(handle == NULL) return;
    printfPtr printfAdr = (printfPtr)GetProcAddress(handle, "printf");
    (*printfAdr)("This is a test\n");
}
```

This is a fast coded working snippet. Doing this was easy because I followed a guide which told me that I could load the `printf` from the `crtdll.dll`. However, now I would like to load the `CreateFileA` function but I don't know how to find the correct dll to load.

I've already tried to Google something and searched on the MSDN but I didn't find anything. In general, given one function (a common one, for example one in `windows.h`, `stdio.h` or `stdlib.h`), how can I find which dll to load?

N.B. I know that some of you may think that loading function this way as no use. However, this is not the real program. In the real one, the addresses `LoadLibraryA` and `GetProcAddress` are manually found and I can write code and then export the segment from the PE.

Comment: Your search on MSDN wasn't very thorough, because the "Requirements" table at the bottom of [the official `CreateFileA` page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) says (in addition to Minimum Windows Version, Header File, and Import Library) "DLL: kernel32.dll"

Comment: Yeah, i found it later, anyway the question didn't change, i needed a way to find dlls for all the function i need and they gave it to me

Comment: FYI, crtdll.dll is a legacy DLL that's only included in SysWOW64 for 32-bit programs. It's not available for 64-bit programs. The version I have in Windows 10 is from 9 Dec 1995, based on the timestamp in the PE header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your example (`printf`) is not a Windows API function, rather it is a function defined in the C standard. Therefore it should be more readily available. However this re-enforces the point that if you don't have any of the either standard or Windows API functions available that makes for a lot of dlls to know about. I don't know of a single place that defines them all in one source file, but you can load your functions on a case by case basis using a resource like [www.pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net) which lets you type in a function name and retrieve the name of the dll to load (as well as the C# method signature but you don't need that, you already know the C signature).